# when allocateMemory,Netty show OutOfMemoryError

Tags: netty, out-of-memory

I'm using Netty3.2.4 for long connection,when server start ,It works right,but after a few days lete,the server may show OutOfMemoryError, and the detail log infomation is :

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@5cd7f9 - appName: 'perbank', name: 'perbank', context-path: '/perbank'] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:99)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:288)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool$Preallocation.<init>(SocketSendBufferPool.java:155)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool.<init>(SocketSendBufferPool.java:42)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

maybe JVM not do the GC,or maybe many socket connections used because the network is not stable,don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would upgrade to latest 3.5.9.Final and see if the problem is solved by [this fix](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/638).